# Jenkin Pipeline stuck after sh command

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, appium-android

I had created automation framework where selenium and appium android both are used ,
I had setup jenkins on aws ec2 ubuntu , I am using jenkin pipeline to run test

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        APPIUM_PORT= 5555
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "GIT.."
                git credentialsId: 'gitHubCred', url: 'https://username_qa_automation.git'

            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Testing.."
                withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin']) {
                sh "appium --port ${APPIUM_PORT}"}
            }
        }
        stage('Run Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Running...."
                sh "mvn clean test -DsuiteXml=testng.xml -Denv=dev -Dbrowser=chrome -Dplatform=android"
            }
        }

        stage('Kill Appium') {
              steps {
                always{
                   echo "Stop appium server"
                     sh "kill \$(lsof -t -i :${APPIUM_PORT})"
                      }
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

When I run build , at console its just stop forever , does not move further , what wrong I am doing here , I am trying this for first time

```
+ appium --port 5555
[35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v1.21.0
[35m[Appium][39m Non-default server args:
[35m[Appium][39m   port: 5555
[35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:5555
```

Comment: `appium` appears to be a service, so the subprocess launched by the shell interpreter will execute forever in the foreground. You probably need to background the process, or could you specify what the intent is here for starting that service in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use & run appium in background so it will move to next command after starting appium server

i.e, sh "appium --port ${APPIUM_PORT}&"}

Answer (score 0):

In  stage('Test') appium is executing `sh "appium --port ${APPIUM_PORT}"}`. This is just listening which seems to make it execute foreover.
 Option would be to configure it as a service.
https://discuss.appium.io/t/is-it-possible-to-run-appium-server-as-a-service-in-linux-like-ubuntu/12916/3